# How can I interact with the Inbox here. What attributes can be used in Protractor?

Tags: protractor

Inspecting this, this is what I got

```
css=.aw-tile-titleMain:nth-child(2).aw-theme-locationsTile.aw-tile-tileName


<div class="aw-tile-tileName ng-binding aw-theme-tileText" ng-class="textClassNames[tile.themeIndex]">            Inbox        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath property if you want to reach to any DOM element. However it would be a better solution if you can reach to element by id. After reaching, you can use:
 `element.sendKeys(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "a", protractor.Key.NULL);` to fill the input field.

Answer (score 0):

```
const inboxDiv = element(by.cssContainingText('div.aw-tile-tileName', 'Inbox'));
```

Then you can do whatever you want with it. Click, clear, sendKeys, any of it will work.

This is assuming that there is no other element on the page that matches that css selector and contains the text "Inbox".